# Как отправлять сообщения в определённый чат с помощью Telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, sendmessage

Умные люди, помогите!

```
to_chat_id="My id (numbers)"

Some code




    for user in supportTeam:
        if message.chat.id > 0:
            bot.send_message(to_chat_id, str(user),
                             str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.first_name + ")" + ": " + message.text[
                                                                                                  message.text.find(
                                                                                                      ' '):].format(
                    message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
        else:
            bot.send_message(to_chat_id, str(user), str(message.chat.id) + " (" + message.chat.title + ")" + ": " + message.text[
                                                                                                        message.text.find(
                                                                                                            ' '):].format(
                    message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: TeleBot.send_message() got multiple values for argument 'parse_mode'
```

Что делать???

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562894/562052

Comment: Amgarak, спасибо огромное!!!